# Does DestroyWindow() remove the messages for the window from the message queue?

Tags: c, winapi

The [DestroyWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says the following:

> The function also destroys the window's menu, flushes the thread
>   message queue,

Does *"flushes the thread message queue"* means that it will remove the messages from the message queue for the window that I want to destroy only?

Comment: That man page says "destroys the associated child or owned windows" so the infererence is it destroys their message queues too. But it would be absurd for the OS to examine every other process, to ferret out and reorganise their message queues. That is like throwing a ball and then saying, oh no, forget that: catch it before it lands because I am now off field.

Comment: Good question, and not made clear by the documentation. My guess would be it flushes the queue only for messages posted to that window and its children.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the message queue belongs to the *thread*, not to the *window* - a single thread can create multiple windows, and can also receive messages not associated with any window, so destroying a particular window can't possibly destroy the thread's message queue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the docs are not explicit on this, it does behave as you suggest. Messages posted to the destroyed window are flushed and those for other windows (or posted to the thread) remain in the thread's queue.

The following sample program demonstrates this - if your suggestion is true, no asserts should fire (and in my tests, they don't).

As @HarryJohnston points out in the comments, destroying one window own by a thread does not destroy any other windows the thread owns (except for children and owned windows of the destroyed window), and so it could be quite problematic if their posted messages were removed, effectively for no reason.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>  

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    assert(message != WM_APP + 1);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex{};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"msgflushtest";
    assert(RegisterClassExW(&wcex));

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"msgflushtest", nullptr, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    assert(hWnd);

    assert(PostMessage(hWnd, WM_APP + 1, 0, 0)); // should be flushed
    assert(PostThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_APP + 2, 0, 0)); // should not be flushed

    DestroyWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    assert(!PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, WM_APP + 1, WM_APP + 1, PM_REMOVE));
    assert(PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, WM_APP + 2, WM_APP + 2, PM_REMOVE));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A simple extension of this (with a second window) shows that the behaviour is the same in that case - messages for windows that are not being destroyed are neither dispatched nor removed from the queue.

Comment: (Is `wcex{}` a typo or some new syntax I haven't caught up with?  VS2010 rejects it.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - not typo. new syntax.  old `CL` compiler don't understand it. however we can write `WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {};` and this will be work ok. almost all usual write `WNDCLASSEXW wcex = { 0 };` but `0` here excess - we can initialize structs by zero with `= {}` with any `CL` and with `{}` (without =) begin from some version

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It's called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), introduced in C++11 (so not available in Visual Studio 2010). It was deemed necessary to resolve the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ambiguity.